# Enter sudo password while in expect script

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I have an expect code inside bash script, something like this

```
env input1=${INPUT1} input2=${INPUT2} expect << "EOS"
    set timeout -1
    spawn ./another_script.sh
    expect {
        "Input 1" { send -- "$env(input1)\r";exp_continue }
        "Input 2" { send -- "$env(input2)\r";exp_continue }
        eof
    }
EOS
```

During the execution of `another_script.sh` I am prompted to enter sudo password, but I'm not able since I'm stil in expect.
What can I do in order for me to be able to enter the sudo password and for the script to continue running after that?
I don't want to save the password in the script and then pass it to expect, but I want to be able to type it in.

Comment: Letting the user interactively take control is what the Expect `interact` facility is for.

Comment: I couldn't find a good/working example of using `interact`. I tried something like this `"password for"  { interact -o "\r" return ; exp_continue }`, but one problem is that it is visible what I am typing, and the other one is that after I hit ENTER, nothing happens, ie. the script is not continuing to work.

Comment: I'd probably want to have a `tcl` tag if you want the folks who are `expect` experts here. (`expect` is an extension to the TCL language, not part of bash; since your problems have nothing to do with how you're starting expect from bash, and everything to do with how it behaves after it's started, this isn't particularly a bash question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer from Donal Fellows is the right way to go, but for completeness here is the `interact` solution you were trying for. The command to use is

```
expect {
    "Input 1" { send -- "$env(input1)\r"; exp_continue }
    "Input 2" { send -- "$env(input2)\r"; exp_continue }
    "password for" { stty -echo
                    interact -u tty_spawn_id -o "\r" return
                    stty echo
                    exp_continue }
    eof
}
```

The problem you have is that you are running expect with the script on stdin, so interact has trouble unless you use `-u tty_spawn_id` to get it to work with `/dev/tty` and the user. You need to set the echo on/off on this tty explicitly, as sudo will only have done it on the pty between the spawned command and expect.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way of handling an event like this is to watch for a prompt for the sudo password, supply it, and then continue. But with a long-running script, you'll want to cache the password *within the expect script* so that you don't have to go back to the user for it several times over a few hours. Indeed, for usability you probably need to ask for the password up front rather than waiting until the underlying system needs it.

Fortunately, expect includes support for stty so it's an easy thing to add.

```
env input1=${INPUT1} input2=${INPUT2} expect << "EOS"
    # Prompt for password, cribbed/converted from example on expect(1) manpage
    stty -echo
    send_tty "sudo password: "
    expect_tty -re "(.*)\n"
    send_tty "\n"
    set password $expect_out(1,string)
    stty echo

    # Rest of the script, with clause for sending the password at the right time
    set timeout -1
    spawn ./another_script.sh
    expect {
        "Input 1" { send -- "$env(input1)\r"; exp_continue }
        "Input 2" { send -- "$env(input2)\r"; exp_continue }
        "assword: " { send -- "$password\r"; exp_continue }
        eof
    }
EOS
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. I tried your suggestion, but I'm getting this error ```sudo password: send: spawn id exp0 not open
    while executing
"send_user "\n""``` You mentioned that I can watch for a prompt, supply it and then continue. How can I do that? I think that would be the answer on the original question.

Comment: It could be the way that you're wrapping an expect script inside a bash script (which I just copied from you). I still don't know why people who write expect scripts like doing that.

Comment: It is because I don't want one more file just for the expect script. I have a large bash script, and I'm expecting some prompts in it (Input 1 and Input 2). `Expect` seemed to be the solution for that, so I just "embedded" expect inside bash script.

Comment: @adamm I think I've fixed it by changing `send_user` and `expect_user` to `send_tty` and `expect_tty` respectively. I _think_ `stty` doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: It works now. It is not what I've been looking for in the question, but it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

From `man sudo`:  The sudoers policy caches credentials for 15 minutes, unless overridden in sudoers(5).

With that, call `sudo -v` before calling expect. It checks for the credentials, and if they aren't cached, it will ask for the root password. That way you can enter them before `expect` and later `sudo` commands don't need to ask again.

Comment: The `another_script.sh` is executing for a couple of hours, so the cached credentials timeout in that period.

Comment: @adamm Can you add the relevant commands to `/etc/sudoers` for `NOPASSWD` access?

Comment: I can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

for what you comment I think you have it in cron. In that case you would neeed to run the script as sudo. you can just call it in the sudo crontab. you can access it by running `sudo crontab -e`

Comment: Running in cron is where you absolutely can't talk to the user, and instead have to take the credentials from elsewhere. Of all the options, reading it from a file is among the better. Or you could simply put the script in root's crontab and not need credentials at all…